# SpriteKit generate 3D objects

Tags: swift, 3d, sprite-kit, collada

I'm trying to add an animation with a cube (3D object) in a SpriteKit Swift (game) application.

I havent find anything concrete regarding how to generate 3D objects using SK.
I need some examples as a start point.

Comment: I'm currently trying to combine SpriteKit (2D) and 3D Effects in my game. This is not simple and - as you - not really a common task. So, whoever downgraded the question did not try to achieve this himself, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SKNode has a subclass SK3DNode, which renders the 3D content of a Scene Kit scene as a 2D texture, i.e you need to use Scene Kit for the 3D animation. Other than that, Sprite Kit framework reference doesn't cover subjects relating to 3D rendering.

Comment: could you please give me an example with how to use  SK3DNode for a dice? I do have all the faces of a dice..and i just want to animate a rolling dice. Thank you

Comment: I didn;t find any example on the internet